# get list of all windows form controls used in one form with .net 1.1

Tags: vb.net

Is there any chance to get all the control names that are in a windows form. 
I saw that there are options for newer .net versions , but i'm limited on this project to 1.1 :(

What i tried is this but with 1.1 everything is so hard to find...

```
Public Sub GetAllControlIDs(ByVal c As Windows.Forms.Control, ByVal ids As List(Of String))
        ids.Add(c.ID)
        If c.HasControls() Then
            For Each ch As Windows.Forms.Control In c.Controls
                GetAllControlIDs(ch, ids)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

Private allControlIDs As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
```

Comment: I get some error in this: ByVal ids As List(Of String)). Error is:
List is not defined. Well its an old project...it must be with 1.1

Comment: Where is the top-most call to `GetAllControlIDs`?

Comment: @AFriend : Doesn't matter if he passes it `ByVal` or `ByRef`. A `List(Of T)` is a reference type, passing it `ByVal` still passes its reference pointer (that's how classes work). The only difference is that if you pass it `ByRef` you can _**replace**_ the reference in the original variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With .NET 1.1. there were no generics(.NET 2), so you can't use a `List(Of String)` but you could use an `ArrayList` instead:

```
Public Sub AddAllControlNames(ByVal c As Windows.Forms.Control, ByVal nameList As ArrayList)
    nameList.Add(c.Name)
    For Each ch As Windows.Forms.Control In c.Controls
        AddAllControlNames(ch, nameList)
    Next
End Sub

Private allControlNames As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
```

....

Called from somewhere within the Form(f.e. `Load`):

```
AddAllControlNames(Me, allControlNames)
```

Comment: i get error in c.ID, it says ID is not a member of windows.forms.control. Is there a chane to get the control name and not ID?

Comment: @Сашко Мицевски: Edited my answer

Comment: I think HasControls was never a WinForms function.  Looks like a Web thing.

Comment: @LarsTech: good catch, thanks. It's a webforms method. It's not needed anyway